# Laravel gather data by relational id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my application, I have a posts table, categories tables and category_post table as a post and category have a many to many relationship.

I want to get all posts with their attached categories, but also group them together as on my frontend I want to be a loop over an object and show a list like this,

- **Cooking**

  - Post Number 1
  - Post Number 3
  - Post Number 4
- **Music**

  - Post Number 2
  - Post Number 5
- **Languages**

  - Post Number 6
  - Post Number 7

I know in my controller I can do this,

`$posts = Post::with('categories')->get();`

But I don't how to groupBy a relational attribute or if I can structure the returned data in such a way that I can loop over it to form the list below.

Comment: you could order by category?

Comment: Why not `$categories = Category::with('posts')->get()`

Answer (score 0):

you can get the data from db and then group them the way you want:

```
$posts = Post::with('categories')->get();

$result = $posts->groupBy([
    'categories',
    function ($item) {
        return $item['category_name'];
    },
], $preserveKeys = true);
```

more details about grouping by relation fields in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby

Answer (score 0):

As per given your table: posts and categories tables are the main tables and category_post table is a pivot table which contains the relation between posts and categories table :

So, Your relation should be posts->category_post->categories

```js
$posts = Posts::with('category_post')->get();

$grouped = $posts->groupBy('category_post.category_id');
```

The category_post also related to the categories table for categories data.

Answer (score 0):

In category model you cam setup and `belongsToMany` relation like the following

```php
function posts()
{
   return $this->beongsToMany(Post::class, 'category_post', 'category_id', 'post_id');
}
```

Then do as  [Arun A S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62193656/laravel-gather-data-by-relational-id#comment109995545_62193656) suggested.